# How to add a page to a category in MediaWiki from a tag extension

Tags: mediawiki

I would like to put

```
`<my-extension/>`
```

onto a page and for the page's categories to be equivalent to if I put

```
[[Category:Pages with the my-extension tag]]
```

straight onto the page.

How is that done, please?
I tried to add to the [function that's ?hooked to ParserFirstCallInit](https://github.com/owen-kellie-smith/financial-maths-mediawiki/blob/format/FinancialMathematics/FinancialMathematics.hooks.php)

```
$localParser = new Parser();
$localParser->parse("\n [[Category::Pages with the my-extension tag]] \n");
```

but it didn't work.

Edit 28-10-2015:
I want to sub-categorise the page according to the parameters provided to the tag, so that if I put

```
`<my-extension/>Input 1</my-extension>`
```

on a page, the page's categories are equivalent to putting

```
[[Category:Pages with the my-extension tag]]
[[Category:Pages using Input 1]]
```

straight onto the page.

Comment: Do I understand this right; you want to be able to view which pages are using a specific extension within the article, as you would by reviewing a category page?

Comment: @mezzo Yes, and also  I want to further categorise the pages according to what parameters they use in the extension.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For predefined categories, you can use [tracking categories](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Help:Tracking_categories) which have the advantage of being translatable and can be disabled by editing the MediaWiki namespace.

In your `extension.json`:

```
"TrackingCategories": ["my-extension-category"],
```

In the function that implements `<my-extension>`:

```
$parser->addTrackingCategory( 'my-extension-category' );
```

In your `en.json`:

```
"my-extension-category": "Pages with the my-extension tag",
```

For dynamic categories, you can just call

```
$parser->getOutput()->addCategory( 'Pages with the my-extension tag', '*' /* sort key */ );
```

Comment: It works great, thank you very much.  The tracking and dynamic categories appear at the bottom of the page.  (They don't appear in Special:Categories.)

Comment: My mistake, it works perfectly.  The tracking and dynamic categories appear at the bottom of the page, and (a little while later) in Special:Categories.